# Permission denied when try to fetch records from zoho people

Tags: api, postman, zoho, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to fetch records from zoho people API .. For this i am using POSTMAn. I successfully create token in postman and when i try to apply this link in get field then this shows an error "permission denied" i tried from past few days but did not come up with solution

token i successfully created in zoho people

[image: token created]

Then i use that token in postman like this

[image: postman image]

but this shows an error

```
{
    "error": "Permission denied"
}
```

what should i do ? any help please

Answer (score 0):

I tried your steps but I found that in my case I can access this API

I created my access token from here 
[Zoho people settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daFTP.png)

Zoho people > Settings > Zoho people API

For API reference check this page 
https://www.zoho.com/people/help/api/attendance-api.html#2

Here are my request and response
[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEpL2.png)
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8F5i.png)

Comment: i already created token and access token ,, this is not answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, go to File > Preferences and make sure the "SSL certificate verification" option is ON, as well as the "Send Postman Token header" and "Automatically follow redirects" options. These are the settings I have in my install of Postman and am able to make requests to Zoho API. I suspect the problem may be with how your install of Postman is handling SSL verification.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give permission to read, write, edit ,from the zoho application first